# Change background color on refresh with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble changing the color of the background on each refresh. Any help is appreciated.  Here is my js so far:

```
var colors = ['#760CE8', '#4782B1', '#E8890C'];

var changeBackground = function() {
    document.body.style.background = colors([Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]);
};

changeBackground();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.
In the line

```
document.body.style.background = colors([Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]);
```

you need to remove the parentheses surrounding `[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]`.
Otherwise JS will think that you want to invoke `colors` as a function.
Instead you want to access an array by index. That's what the square brackets do.
So change it to

```
document.body.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
```

and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine just do as @TheShellfishMeme said and put your function in the body tag like this:

```
<body onload="changeBackground();">
```

now on every refresh you get the different body color.

Comment: It's loading fine without adding this since I specified the body in the js. Should I be putting this anyways as part of the convention? Thanks for your time.